# Reputation on area51 is behaving weirdly

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, reputation-audit

The reputation displayed on top does not match the one from the [reputation report](http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation) (/reputation) and *not only* because of deleted proposals; sometimes it adds reputation when I'm capped (by the report), sometimes it doesn't, when I'm capped and get voted NaGE and then I get those 2 points back the reputation adds +5, etc

It's just off, perhaps somebody could take a look at it?

Comment: Mine is showing off by 20 points - 1023 in the rep report, and 1043 on the top of the page.

Comment: Mine is off by 43 - 1910 in the rep vs 1953 accredited.

Comment: It may be off by deleted proposals, but that's *not* what I'm referring to

Comment: I took a quick look at this and it looked like it was capping correctly.  Remember that (unlike the other sites) users can undo their votes at any time, which messes up the cap because they could do it many days after they initially cast their vote.  If you still see something funny going on, I can take a closer look.

Comment: Perhaps that's it @David, though the audit report seemed to be ok while the displayed reputation was doing that funny stuff. If I find more exact information I'll post it here. Thanks!

Comment: @David and what about reputation from the discussion zone, i had one question with some upvotes, for about a two or three weeks, and this upvotes not counted in my rep (should they counts somewhere?)

Comment: @igor the discussion zone acts like a linked meta site, where reputation is not counted.

Comment: @David thanks now it make sense why it's not changed. Well it weird to have votes that not change anything, but it's Area 51..that place should be weird)